# Exception handling custom middleware dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I am facing very strange issue where in, i am using a custom middleware to validate to validate the headers being passed to my api and then executes the constructor of a class with a scoped lifetime. On the first request to the API if the class constructor throws an exception, on the subsequent requests the code does not reach my class but however the same exception is returned. Can someone please help me understand what is causing this?

Middleware:

```
public class HeaderValidator
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public HeaderValidator(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ITenantValidator tenantValidator)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(Constant.s_tenant_header))
            {
                context.Request.Headers.Add(Constant.s_tenant_header, TenantId.US.ToString());
            }

            //Allow '/health' endpoint calls without header info and reject all other calls if header x-tenant is not passed
            if (!context.Request.Path.Equals("/health") && !context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(Constant.s_tenant_header))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("'x-tenant' must be provided in the header");
            }
            //Allow '/health' endpoint calls without header info and reject calls if 'x-tenant' is not supported
            else if (!context.Request.Path.Equals("/health") && !tenantValidator.IsValidTenant(context?.Request?.Headers[Constant.s_tenant_header]))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Provided 'x-tenant' is not supported");
            }
            else
                await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"exception during processing");
        }
    }
}
```

Class registration:

```
services.AddScoped<IChannelToken, ChannelToken>()
```

Middlewares registered:

```
app.UseMiddleware<HeaderValidator>();
app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
app.UseStatusCodePages();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: Can you please post somewhere a full [mre]?

Comment: Is there something like response caching involved?

Comment: There is no response caching involved.

Comment: Your question states the middleware calls a constructor, but it doesn't. It also states a constructor throws an exception, but the only constructor in the code cannot possibly throw an exception. Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What do you have inside `ITenantValidator tenantValidator` interface? Could you please share the details in order to reproduce your issue?